# Javascript send array to PHP using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send an array from javascript to PHP script using ajax. This is the code I have so far.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while (++$i <= $_SESSION['totalcolumns']) {
    $range = $_SESSION["min-column-$i"] . ',' . $_SESSION["max-column-$i"];?>
        <br><?php echo "Keyword" ?>
        <?php echo $i -1 ?>
        <br><input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="<?php echo $range ?>" data-slider-step="1">
        <?php } ?>
        <button type="button" >Update</button>
<script>
    $("[data-slider]")
       .each(function () {
           var range;
            var input = $(this);
            $("<span>").addClass("output")
                .insertAfter(input);
            range = input.data("slider-range").split(",");
            $("<span>").addClass("range")
                .html(range[0])
                .insertBefore(input);
            $("<span>").addClass("range")
                .html(range[1])
                .insertAfter(input);
        })
        .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
            $(this).nextAll(".output:first")
                .html(data.value.toFixed(2));
        });
        $(".output")
        .each(function() {
        var parms = [];
        parms.push($(this).text());
        });


</script>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
        {
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update.php",
                    data: { value : $(parms).serializeArray() },
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        console.log (data);
                    }
                }); 

}
$("button").on('click',function(){ loadXMLDoc(); });
</script>
```

In my **$.output** function, I am using the **parms []** array to store all the UI slider values which I am trying to pass on to the next PHP script page on a button click event as defined in **loadXMLDoc()** function. In my PHP page, I am accessing them as below.

```
<?php

    $uid = $_POST['value'];
    echo "Am I getting printed";
    echo $uid;
    // Do whatever you want with the $uid
?>
```

However, I am not able to view the data in my update.php script. Can someone please let me know what am doing wrong?

This is the [link](http://omega.uta.edu/~rxv1100/slider.php) to  my work so far.

Comment: data: "value"+parms, IN php  $uid = $_POST['value']; ?

Comment: ReferenceError: parms is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

data: { value : parms },  ???

Comment: I am defining the parms [] in $output function and trying to use it in the $loadXMLDoc function. Basically, I am trying to send the slider values on button click.

Comment: define this global var parms [] ;

Comment: I am not getting anything in my page.

Comment: I am editing the file in notepad ++ and uploading it in the server. Which tool are you using to run the PHP codes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39145/discussion-between-samitha-and-ram-esh)

Answer (score 0):

serializeArray returns the json object ,maybe you could try json_decode in your php script,simply like:

```
$uid_arr = json_decode($uid,true);
print_r($uid_arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting out. I tried it out but it's not working.

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful comment. What did the print_r show? No data? Wrong Data?

Answer (score 0):

Just Use

```
data:  $(parms).serializeArray()
```